# C# mysql database connection class object error

Tags: c#

Im new to C# and I just create a database connection using mysql. Then I need to define a database connection class here this is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace restsurant_pos
{
    class mysqlDbConnect
    {

          public static MySqlConnection GetConnection(){
            string MyConnectionString = "Server=Localhost;Database=pos;Uid=root;Pwd='';";
            MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConnectionString);
            MySqlCommand cmd;
            connection.Open();

            return connection;

          }
```

hope it is correct..

then how can I create a object using this class. I just created a as below, but it is getting an error.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace restsurant_pos
{
    public partial class AddCategory : Form
    {

        public AddCategory()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btn_insertCategory_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string categoryName = txtCategoryName.Text;

            mysqlDbConnect connection = new mysqlDbConnect();

            try
            {
                cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO categories(name) VALUES(@categoryName)";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("categoryName", txtCategoryName.Text);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                this.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }

            finally 
            {
                if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open) {
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

what is the wrong with my code.. pls help

Comment: It looks like you haven't defined `cmd`. Try putting `var` or `MySqlConnection` in front of it

Answer (score 2):

You haven't providing a `type` for `cmd`.

Solve it by declaring it (lazily) as `var cmd = connection.CreateCommand()` or use a hard coded type.

Comment: yes cmd solved... but `connection.CreateCommand();` ,`connection.State` and `connection.Close();` still remaining...

Comment: you need to use `connection.Open()`. Right now you've created a connection, but not opened it.

Comment: also, "still remaining" isn't exactly descriptive. What are the errors..?

Comment: `Error 2 'restsurant_pos.mysqlDbConnect' does not contain a definition for 'CreateCommand' and no extension method 'CreateCommand' accepting a first argument of type 'restsurant_pos.mysqlDbConnect' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\vb\restsurant_pos\restsurant_pos\AddCategory.cs 29 38 restsurant_pos
`

Comment: `Error 3 'restsurant_pos.mysqlDbConnect' does not contain a definition for 'State' and no extension method 'State' accepting a first argument of type 'restsurant_pos.mysqlDbConnect' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\vb\restsurant_pos\restsurant_pos\AddCategory.cs 42 32 restsurant_pos
`

Comment: `Error 4 'restsurant_pos.mysqlDbConnect' does not contain a definition for 'Close' and no extension method 'Close' accepting a first argument of type 'restsurant_pos.mysqlDbConnect' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\vb\restsurant_pos\restsurant_pos\AddCategory.cs 43 33 restsurant_pos
`

Comment: You need a connection string and to actually `Open()` the connection.